# Explanation for SQL use of '&'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone please explain this to me?  I'm working with some SQL code (for MS SQL Server) written by someone else and there's something I've never seen before: the use of the '&' operator in the Where clause as follows:

```
select Field_A, Field_B
from Table_1
where Field_E = 1
and Field_D & 2 = 0
```

The 'Field_D' is integer format with possible values of 1, 2, 4, and 5.  Help will be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: In some databases, the `&` means bit-wise AND.  It can also mean string concatenation, and might have other meanings.

Comment: This question specifically refers to Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I now believe it is a bitwise evaluation as suggested.